How to manually add boot entry using Windows command prompt located in ext4 partition
I have 2 SSDs, one for Windows, and one for additional Windows games/Arch Linux (I have 5 partitions on it, 2 for Windows and 3 for Arch Linux.) For some reason, my BIOS isn't detecting GRUB anymore, so I think I need to manually add it somehow. I can't add it through my BIOS because I have a basic Insyde BIOS and it doesn't give me the option of manually booting from EFI files. I installed LinuxReader and it found the GRUB EFI file in FAT32 Volume 3/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi. Now the question is, is there a way to add the boot entry from Windows, despite the EFI file being on an ext4 filesystem?

No, the .efi file is not "on an EXT4 filesystem" (you're confusing it with a mountpoint inside the Linux tree). All bootloaders are installed in the ESP (EFI System Partition, FAT32). What you need to clarify is this: my BIOS isn't detecting GRUB anymore. Please [edit] the question accordingly. If it boot Windows directly just say so, not assume other things. Have you already checked UEFI - Boot menu? There you can change the OS selection... And the OS being installed in one or several drives is irrelevant here.

BTW, LinuxReader (and DiskGenius) do a good job reading from ext4 partitions, but not writing to them. However, that is irrelevant to the issue you have, which needs more explanation.
